# Un-responsive docker containers

Tags: docker, containerd

I see that docker containers in my host show as Running/Up , however when I try to exec , I see .

`rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found`

I don't see any related processes running on `ps -aef` output.

Looking through the `dockerd` logs I see -

> `level=error msg="containerd: get exit status" error="containerd:
>   process has not exited" id=e4e5d58359 pid=bba1944c4 systemPid=5132`

docker version:

> Client:  Version:      1.13.1  API version:  1.26  Go
>   version:   go1.7.5  Git commit:   092cba3  Built:        Wed Feb  8
>   06:50:14 2017  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
>
> Server:  Version:      1.13.1  API version:  1.26 (minimum version
>   1.12)  Go version:   go1.7.5  Git commit:   092cba3  Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:50:14 2017  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64  Experimental: false

What might be causing this behavior ? Pointers?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed since v17.12.

Version 18.03 is the latest supported release so you should do upgrade your docker to latest edition.

Comment: I looked through the changelog https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#18031-ce , can you help me identify the correct line item.

Comment: A lot of people had the same problems on Git. Look at below: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35091, https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22909, https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1 etc.